# How can I quickly display failure details while using pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

Pytest is able to provide nice traceback errors for the failed tests but is doing this after all the tests were executed and I am interested in displaying the errors progressively.

I know that one workaround would be to make it fail fast at the first error, but I do not want this, I do want it to continue.

Answer (score 6):

Checkout [pytest-instafail](https://github.com/jpvanhal/pytest-instafail):

> pytest-instafail is a plugin for py.test that shows failures and errors instantly instead of waiting until the end of test session.

Comment: Alternatively pytet-sugar also behaves like this

Answer (score 0):

Use fail tag

py.test -r f

PyTest will returns just the names of the failing tests, line numbers of where the fail occurred and the type of error that caused the failure.

Comment: This still waits until all tests are complete before returning anything, so it doesn't answer the question.